# Interpreting CSF emails

Tags: firewall, csf

I get emails from CSF every time it blocks someone.  Here's one I got this morning:

```
Time:    Sat Jan 19 10:17:24 2013 -0800
IP:      <REDACTED> (US/United States/-)
Hits:    21
Blocked: Temporary Block

Sample of block hits:
Jan 19 10:16:28 red kernel: [6727856.279786] Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<REDACTED> DST=<REDACTED> LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=47609 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40954 DPT=587 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Jan 19 10:16:30 red kernel: [6727858.716317] Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<REDACTED> DST=<REDACTED> LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=40975 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43688 DPT=587 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Jan 19 10:16:31 red kernel: [6727859.809269] Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<REDACTED> DST=<REDACTED> LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=56375 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43688 DPT=587 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
.....  (It continues on with more of the same)
```

The way I'm reading this is that this particular IP (SRC, right?) got blocked because of excessive hits to port 587 (DPT, right?) (which is SMTP).  Am I correct?  Are there any other important bits I should know how to read?  Google wasn't helping when I tried to learn how to decipher these things.

And then the matter of interpreting:  This happens to be my business partner's IP.  He says he wasn't sending any emails at the time.  Any theories on what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen that someone was trying to connect your server on port 587 with incorrect login details, so csf/lfd has blocked that IP.

In the same way might your partner has incorrect attempts for cpanel/mail and Ip has blocked, you can check same as:

> csf -g (partner's IP)

or

> grep (partner's IP) /etc/csf/*

and if you see entry in csf.deny or csf.tempip then remove that entry to unblock that ip.